# How would I remove letters at an even position throughout a string in Java?

Tags: java

```
        
        String evensRemoved = "";
        
        String str = reversedNames[1];
        
        String noSpaces = str.replace(" ","");
        
        int strlength = noSpaces.length();
        
        for(int i = 0; i <= strlength; i++){
            
            if(i % 2 == 0){
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(noSpaces);
                sb.deleteCharAt(i);
                
                String result = sb.toString();
                
                return result;
            }
        }
        
        return "";
```

I want to be able to remove letters at even positions throughout the string completely, and then return the string to the original method. I've looked at other solutions and haven't been able to figure it out at all. New to Java.

Comment: Looping through string and checking if the index is odd append that char to new string starting with empty will do the trick, append can be done like newString += string.chatAt(index)

Comment: You shouldn't return after your first removal. I'd also suggest going through the string backwards, because if you go forwards then the even/odd changes. Think of string = "1234" When you delete '2', then the string is "134". '4' is now at an odd position, and can't be deleted.

Comment: You might want to go through the String backwards to preserve the even/odd values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

- It uses a regex that takes two chars at a time and replaces them with the 2nd, thus removing every other one.
- the `(.)` is a capture group of 1 character.
- `$1` is a back reference to it.

```
   String s = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
   s = s.replaceAll("(?s).(.)?", "$1");
   System.out.println(s);
```

Prints

```
bdfhjlnprtvxz
```

per [Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5221149/andreas) suggestion, I preceded the regex with a flag that lets `.` match returns and linefeeds.

Comment: Might want to prefix regex with `(?s)`, so `.` matches ``\r`` and ``\n`` characters too. Probably a non-issue, but you never know.

Comment: In Java 9+, it should be `"\\X(\\X)?"`, so it correctly handles grapheme clusters.

Comment: I'll let your comment speak for itself.  They can make the change if they want.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

To remove all characters at even indexes, copy all the characters at odd indexes to a new `char[]`.

```java
public static String removeEvens(String str) {
    char[] buf = new char[str.length() / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++)
        buf[i] = str.charAt(i * 2 + 1);
    return new String(buf);
}
```

*Test*

```java
String str = "0123456789";
for (int i = 0; i <= str.length(); i++) {
    String sub = str.substring(0, i);
    System.out.println('"' + sub + "\" -> \"" + removeEvens(sub) + '"');
}
```

*Output*

```
"" -> ""
"0" -> ""
"01" -> "1"
"012" -> "1"
"0123" -> "13"
"01234" -> "13"
"012345" -> "135"
"0123456" -> "135"
"01234567" -> "1357"
"012345678" -> "1357"
"0123456789" -> "13579"
```